# How create new OpenCV Mat object with GCC compiler?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I have gray Mat (image). I wanna create color image the same size as gray image:
With Visual C++ Express it compiled:

```
Mat dst = cvCreateImage(gray.size(), 8, 3);
```

but with GCC compiler is error:

```
threshold.cpp|462|error: conversion from ‘IplImage* {aka _IplImage*}’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested|
```

I change to cvCreateMat

```
Mat dst = cvCreateMat(gray.rows, gray.cols, CV_8UC3);
```

but GCC still:

```
threshold.cpp|462|error: conversion from ‘CvMat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested|
```

Is method create directly Mat or is any conversion?

Answer (score 4):

```
cvCreateImage(gray.size(), 8, 3);
```

is from the old , deprecated c-api. don't use it (it's actually creating an IplImage*).

construct a cv::Mat like this:

```
Mat dst(gray.size(), CV_8UC3); // 3 uchar channels
```

note, that you will never have to pre-allocate anything for *result* images,

so, if i.e. you want to do a threshold operation, it's just:

```
Mat gray = ....;
Mat thresh; // intentionally left empty!
threshold( gray,thresh, 128,255,0);
// .. go on working with thresh. no need to release it either.
```